# Gnuplot: encircle data points

Tags: gnuplot

I have two sets of data points, which I plot on a single graph. I would like to surround data points belonging to one data set with a circle (preferable dashed line).

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) find the centroid (average of the data points), 2) find the distance to the data point that is farthest from that centroid, 3) draw a circle with the centroid at its center and with a slightly larger radius than that distance. There are other ways as well, that might be better if you have a couple distant outliers. But you should try it yourself and show us what effort you've made...

Comment: I am not looking for a circle like this, I need a tight fit - does not need to be a circle.

Comment: In that case, you probably want the centroid of the convex hull of the data points. But your question is extremely vague, so a precise answer is a bit difficult to provide...

Comment: If you just want to change the drawing for each point just try different point types: "plot ... pt 7" gives you circles. Other numbers give you different stuff.